# How to make the scrollview scrollable in reduced view area when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard, frame

I have embedded all my views in a UIScrollView from xib. The scrollview contents cover all screen below status bar. Now when the textfield is tapped, I am able to move the scrollview little up. But I want it to be completely scrollable till the bottom most view is also visible above the keyboard. Also when the scrollview is scrolled till top , it should come to normal original positions. Hence, Overall I want a completely scrollable functionality like mentioned above for my scrollview.

I am done with following tricks but with no luck:

Trick 1: Change the height of the scrollview so that the content is more than scrollview height and hence the view is scrollable:

```
-(void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)sender
{
CGFloat y_offset=0;

if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480){
    y_offset = 80;
} else {
    y_offset = 70;
}
NSDictionary* userInfo = [sender userInfo];

CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];
keyboardHeight = keyboardEndFrame.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, - y_offset, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];


[self.loginScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.loginScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.loginScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.loginScrollView.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - keyboardHeight)];
}

-(void)keyboardWillDisappear:(NSNotification *)sender
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];
[self.loginScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.loginScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.loginScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.loginScrollView.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
}
```

Trick 2: As per other suggestions, I changed the contentInset of the UIScrollView.

In keyboardWillAppear method I added following code:

```
  CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
  UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+100, 0.0);
  self.loginScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
  self.loginScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```

and in keyboardWillDisappear method I set the contentInset back to zero values.

Hence, let me know if there needs to be any other way to sort this out or any other possible changes I need to make in scrollview frame. Moreover , if I turn on the bouncesVertically functionality it is able to bounce even when complete subviews are visible onscreen which I don't want. So basically I want it to freeze when keyboard is not there and scrollable till viewable area when it is up. Hence, give me any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first approach, set the scroll view _contentSize_ equal to your full screen size(without keyboard present) along with the frame adjustment to view what you already did.

Comment: yep , that works like charm!! Thanks @Gandalf. Please post it as an answer so that everyone knows the solution and I shall accept the same. :)

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I have posted the answer. You may accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a conceptual point of view when "**scrollView Size == scrollView ContentSize**", it does not scroll. To make it scrollable we need to increase the *contentSize*. In your problem you need to adjust the *contentSize* of scrollView along with frame. This can be done in your first approach.

As for the second approach, changing the edge insets will create a sort of padding for the content drawable area. This can make the bottom content visible, but it won't affect the *contentSize*, hence view will not be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

```
[self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
```

}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

```
[self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
```

}

-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{

```
    const int movementDistance = -60; // change this size if you need
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // change this size if you need

    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

it is useful for me

Comment: I am able to move the view up . But I want scrollview to be completely scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

I can really recommend this library:
https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

It's very very easy to use, and works for ScrollView, TableView and CollectionView!

Comment: Except that it broke for me in iOS 8.  (https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/issues/129)